# Android html5 audio playback fail

Tags: android, html, audio, stream, progressive

I made a html page ,and put an audio tag in it then I try to use my android browser to play some music .

But it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<audio id='simple-audio-player' src="http://m.html5/baidu.mp3" controls="controls" preload="metadata"></audio>

window.onload = function () {
  var au = document.getElementById("simple-audio-player");
  au.load();

  if(au.networkState != au.NETWORK_NO_SOURCE){
    alert('au.networkState != au.NETWORK_NO_SOURCE');
    try{
        au.play();
    }catch(err){
        alert(err);
    }
  }else{
    alert('au.networkState == au.NETWORK_NO_SOURCE');
  }
```

};

I think it would be something wrong with my IIS config ,but I not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can't play audio from the window load event, it has to happen in response to a user interaction.

Like this...

```
window.addEventListener('ontouchstart', onStart);

function onStart()
{
    var audio = new Audio(); // --or-- document.getElementById('id-of-audio-tag');
    audio.src = "test.mp3";
    audio.play();
}
```